# Metamask show Select your account dialog

Tags: metamask

I have a website that allows you to link more wallets. When user is already connected with one of the accounts to the website and he clicks **Add more wallets** button it triggers Signature request dialog. However the problem is that the user may not know that he needs to switch account inside Metamask and click Connect inside Metamask before clicking Add more wallets button so proper wallet will be used for signature.

Is there any way to show Select your account dialog first? The exactly the same as Metamask shows when you arrive to some website first time and you don't have any account connected yet.
[image]